# Cannot use d3.values() on json object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the latest versionof d3 and need to get the minimum and maximum values of a nested property of a JSON object which looks like this:

```
const data =
{
 "Item1":{
   "Property1": "11",
   "Property2": "12",
 },
 "Item2":{
   "Property1": "21",
   "Property2": "22",
 }
}
```

To get the minimum value of `Property1` I know that I cannot directly use `d3.min` on an object so I tried to convert it first into an array by doing the following:

```
const min = d3.min(d3.values(data, (d) => +d.Property1))
```

VScode tells me that there are no errors but on the console it tells me that "values" it's not a function. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

d3.values is equivalent of Object.values which takes only one parameter while I see you are passing two parameters , so that is why an error. I have done an example snippet for you to get the minimum, for each Item object, you can map it to get property1 value which is at index 0 ( you do this again by using d3.values). You get minimum of the property1. Note: If you dont do parseInt below, your data will give minimum based on string i.e. 100 will be lesser than 2 ( take care of that)

There can be a better answer to that by replacing 0 index with indexOf(propertyname) if you have an array of Properties. You can give a try.

**UPDATE: d3.values is not supported in d3v7, so use Object.values instead**

```js
const data =
{
 "Item1":{
   "Property1": "151",
   "Property2": "12",
 },
 "Item2":{
   "Property1": "21",
   "Property2": "22",
 },
 "Item3":{
   "Property1": "12",
   "Property2": "452",
 },
  "Item4":{
   "Property1": "100",
   "Property2": "4",
 }
}

const min = d3.min(Object.values(data).map(function(d) {
    return parseInt(Object.values(d)[0]);}));

console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.4/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-hnFpvCiJ8Fr1lYLqcw6wLgFUOEZ89kWCkO+cEekwcWPIPKyknKV1eZmSSG3UxXfsSuf+z/SgmiYB1zFOg3l2UQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the console still won't like it...here's the error message: "App.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: https_cdn_skypack_dev_d3_7__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.values is not a function"

Comment: I think d3 v7 has deprecated the same as Object.values is same as it is. Use Object.values (object). @marco I have replaced the above code..Hope that helps.